# Have Facebook prompt for a security code when I change profile picture or change profile information

Tags: facebook, security

Is there a way to setup my Facebook account to ask me for a security code every time I change my profile picture or post a status message?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way as of now to do this. But you can to write a wrapper [application](http://developers.facebook.com/) that has permissions to post statuses and change your profile picture on your behalf if you enter the correct security code.

This application cannot block the existing way of posting statuses and photos rather it will be just a way around.